# Create copy of plone installed onto another server with data

Tags: python, linux, plone

To create another exact copy of the plone install running along with data, is it sufficient to copy buildout.cfg and Data.fs with same version of Plone on the other install? Does it restore the uploaded pdf and image files that have been done on the first server?
Using plone 4.2.1 standalone install on linux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right that you also need to transfer files and images. They are stored as BLOBs on the file system.

I guess that you will find a directory named `blobstorage`, close to the `filestorage` directory where you found `Data.fs`.

You need to transfer this `blobstorage` directory and all its content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/598733/godefroid-chapelle so it restores the users / groups with versions of uploaded files also?

Comment: Which users/groups are you asking about ? OS or Plone ? If you ask about Plone users and you have not installed any user-related plugins in your plone site, yes, they will be restored.